# Create a sql view statement using an EXIST command

Tags: mysql, sql, view, create-view

I have to write a create view statement in sql that uses an exist command. I tried looking it up online, but Ive had some difficulty. I tried my best to write the create view file but it isnt working right now. I know I need to use the keyword EXIST in my statement. The statement I am trying to create is

```
Write a query that shows returns the name and city of the university that has no people in database
that are associated with it.
```

The code that I have written so far is this

```
CREATE VIEW exist AS
SELECT a.university_name, a.city
FROM lab5.university as a
INNER JOIN lab5.person as b
ON a.uid = b.uid
WHERE b.uid  NOT EXIST
```

The tables that I am using are

```
         Table "table.university"
     Column      |         Type          |                        Modifiers     
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 uid             | integer               | not null default nextval('university_uid_seq'::regclass)
 university_name | character varying(50) | 
 city            | character varying(50) |
```

AND

```
            Table "table.person"
 Column |         Type          |                      Modifiers                       
--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 pid    | integer               | not null default nextval('person_pid_seq'::reg class)
 uid    | integer               | 
 fname  | character varying(25) | not null
 lname  | character varying(25) | not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use the below code and let me know the feedback

> CREATE VIEW checkuni AS 
>   SELECT a.university_name, a.city FROM
>   university as a 
>   WHERE NOT EXISTS
>   (SELECT p.uid FROM person as  p
>   WHERE p.uid = a.uid)

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS is a predicate so your query should look something like:

```
SELECT a.university_name, a.city
FROM lab5.university as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM lab5.person as b
    WHERE a.uid = b.uid
);
```

You could also express the same thing using an outer join and the `IS NULL` predicate:

```
SELECT a.university_name, a.city
FROM lab5.university as a
LEFT JOIN lab5.person as b
    ON a.uid = b.uid
WHERE b.uid IS NULL
```

In some circumstances you may need to use a `SELECT DISTINCT` but I guess that wont be necessary in your case.